# inserting a premade email contact form into website

Tags: php, html, css

I have very little knowledge of php so I went ahead and used one from css-tricks email forms he set up for free use:http://css-tricks.com/nice-and-simple-contact-form/.

However I am not sure how to put it into the website without breaking the php code. I assume I can't simply just take the code that I want, which is

```
<div id="contact-area">

        <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />

            <label for="City">City:</label>
            <input type="text" name="City" id="City" />

            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

            <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
            <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        </form>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

        <p>Check out a <a href="http://css-tricks.com/examples/NiceSimpleContactForm2">version of this</a> with SPAM protection.</p>

    </div>
```

and put it into my html page. I tried using an iframe to link the html page into my html page for my website and it worked, but is this method ok?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just place that coding in your HTML page as long as all the webpage and css file's are linked correctly.(e.g. In the same folder as this page with the coding you have now.)
Using an i-frame for this is *not* a good idea as it can really mess up your pages and submitting your form.

Comment: what if they're in a different folder? or should I not run that risk and put them in the same folder as my original html page?

Comment: @nachime It is simpler, but messier, to keep them all in the same folder. If you want them in a different folder, try making a sub-folder inside the original html pages foler called "contact" and place all the files in it then link to it like: "contact/contactengine.php"